# Generic Type Not Resolving to Union

Tags: typescript

The below code errors:

```
class Base { }

class Child1 extends Base {
  child1Fn() {}
  static deserialize(bytes: Uint8Array): Child1 {
    return new Child1();
  }
}

class Child2 extends Base {
  child2Fn() {}
  static deserialize(bytes: Uint8Array): Child2 {
    return new Child2();
  }
}

const childMap = {
  "child1": Child1.deserialize,
  "child2": Child2.deserialize
}

function deserialize<T>(
  data: { name: string, bytes: Uint8Array },
  deserializeMap: Record<string, (bytes: Uint8Array) => T>
): T {
  const deserializeFn = deserializeMap[data.name];
  if (deserializeFn) {
    return deserializeFn(data.bytes)
  }
}

function deserializeChildMap(data: { name: string, bytes: Uint8Array }) {
  return deserialize(data, childMap)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aclass%20Base%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child1%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20child1Fn()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20static%20deserialize(bytes%3A%20Uint8Array)%3A%20Child1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Child1()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child2%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20child2Fn()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20static%20deserialize(bytes%3A%20Uint8Array)%3A%20Child2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Child2()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20childMap%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22child1%22%3A%20Child1.deserialize%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22child2%22%3A%20Child2.deserialize%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20deserialize%3CT%3E(%0D%0A%20%20data%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%2C%20bytes%3A%20Uint8Array%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20deserializeMap%3A%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20(bytes%3A%20Uint8Array)%20%3D%3E%20T%3E%0D%0A)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20deserializeFn%20%3D%20deserializeMap%5Bdata.name%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(deserializeFn)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20deserializeFn(data.bytes)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20deserializeChildMap(data%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%2C%20bytes%3A%20Uint8Array%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20deserialize(data%2C%20childMap)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

I end up with the error:

```
Argument of type '{ "child1": (bytes: Uint8Array) => Child1; "child2": (bytes: Uint8Array) => Child2; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, (bytes: Uint8Array) => Child1>'.
  Property '"child2"' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '(bytes: Uint8Array) => Child2' is not assignable to type '(bytes: Uint8Array) => Child1'.
      Property 'child1Fn' is missing in type 'Child2' but required in type 'Child1'.
```

It looks to resolve the type `T` to be the first return value in childMap (Child1). Ideally, I would want `T` to resolve to `Child1 | Child2`. Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, but it requires a few more generic type parameters:

```
class Base { }

class Child1 extends Base {
  child1Fn() { }
  static deserialize(bytes: Uint8Array): Child1 {
    return new Child1();
  }
}

class Child2 extends Base {
  child2Fn() { }
  static deserialize(bytes: Uint8Array): Child2 {
    return new Child2();
  }
}

const childMap = {
  "child1": Child1.deserialize,
  "child2": Child2.deserialize
}

function deserialize<TName extends string, TMap extends Record<TName, (bytes: Uint8Array) => any>>(
  data: { name: TName, bytes: Uint8Array },
  deserializeMap: TMap
): ReturnType<TMap[TName]> {
  const deserializeFn = deserializeMap[data.name];
  if (deserializeFn) {
    return deserializeFn(data.bytes)
  }
}

function deserializeChildMap<TName extends keyof typeof childMap>(data: { name: TName, bytes: Uint8Array }): ReturnType<typeof childMap[TName]> {
  return deserialize(data, childMap)
}

let c1 = deserializeChildMap({ name: "child1", bytes: null!}) // child1 
let c2 = deserializeChildMap({ name: "child2", bytes: null!}) // child2
```

Answer (score 0):

[Titian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54916152/1715579) is excellent. Just for the sake of completeness, here's my stab at it:

```
function deserialize<T>(
  data: { name: string, bytes: Uint8Array },
  deserializeMap: { [key in keyof T]: (bytes: Uint8Array) => T[key] }
): T[keyof T] {
  const deserializeFn = deserializeMap[data.name];
  if (deserializeFn) {
    return deserializeFn(data.bytes)
  }
}
```

The signature of `deserializeChildMap` is now inferred as:

```
function deserializeChildMap(data: { name: string; bytes: Uint8Array; }): Child1 | Child2
```